# Order Parameter for Gas-Liquid systems, analogy to magnetic case

Tags: statistical-mechanics, critical-phenomena

I've read that the order parameter for gas-liquid systems is $m=\rho_l-\rho_g$, while the corresponding ordering field is $h=P-P_c$.
I have some issue with this, because it doesn't seem analogous to the magnetic case, where the $m=M/N$ and $h=B$.

More specifically, for a magnetic material, when $B=0$ and $T<T_c$ the order parameter is different from zero.
Doing the same for a fluid seems no-sense, $P-P_c=0$ is the analogous to $B=0$, but evaluating $\rho_l-\rho_g$ is meaningless because there is only one equilibrium state for $P=P_c$ and a given temperature $T<T_c$ which is not biphasic.[image]

A picture of the point at $P=P_c$ and temperature $T$ such that $T<T_c$

Comment: There is no obvious symmetry-breaking (i.e zero in one phase non-zero in  the other) order parameter for liquid-gass transitions as there is for magnets.  The nearest analogue is the interphase surface tension.

Comment: sorry, i think i don't have enough knowledge to see how this should help me

Comment: maybe you can improve the title to be more descriptive so that people searching the site can better get an idea of the contents of your question.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero done, i hope this is more useful, sorry for it.

Comment: Are you sure you want $P_c$ and not the saturation pressure $P_s$ (i.e., the pressure at the plateau)? The latter certainly corresponds to $h=0$ in the lattice gas interpretation of the Ising model (namely, $P_s$ is the pressure at the value of the chemical potential at which the first-order transition takes place, which corresponds to $h=0$ in the magnetic interpretation). You can find this discussed in more detail in Section 4.8 of [this book](https://www.unige.ch/math/folks/velenik/smbook).